# What assets are needed in the public github repo for update.electronjs.org/.../darwin-x64/0.1.0 to return a valid response?

Tags: macos, installation, electron

Hello wonderful Stack Overflow world,

I have an Electron application succesfully deployed and auto-updating for my Windows customers using and  `update-electron-app`.

I also have a working, signed and packaged installer for MacOS.

What assets do I need to put into the public github repo for the  `https://update.electronjs.org/{{owner}}/{{repo}}/darwin-x64/0.1.0` request to return a valid response? The latest version number is `3.8.76`

I am receiving:
`No updates found (needs asset matching *(mac|darwin|osx).*(-arm).*.zip in public repository)`

In my repo, I have uploaded a zip of the signed dmg produced by using `electron-packager`, `codesign` and `electron-installer-dmg`.

It is named: `app_name-setup_mac-arm-version.dmg.zip`, passing the regular expression provided in the failed http response.

I have tried zipping the traditional way, and using `electron-installer-zip` (which produces a MUCH larger file) to no effect.

Any insights most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Sparked into life when I removed `-arm` from the file name.

It appears I can’t read regex, or the error response message is rather confusing.

Now receiving a nice response:

```
{"name":"v3.8.76","notes":"","url":"https://github.com/owner/repo/releases/download/v3.8.76/appName-setup_mac-3.8.76.dmg.zip"}
```

:)